# Text cutoff from right using pure css

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the effect of right top border cutting off the text but not getting anything near it.
Can anyone help me out with this effect as shown in the picture.
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Oh...and **clip-path**...start there.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
  background: #E2E2E2;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.wrapper::after{
  content: " ";

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
  border-right: 15px solid white;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">Your text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

some other ways :

1) use png image and use position absolute

2) clip-path as Paulie_D suggested in the comments

Answer (score 0):

**A - when you have fixed width of button:** (and its background-color may be transparent):
You can put three divs one inside another:

- the second one will be rotated and will have inset shadow-box
- the third one will be roteted in opposite direction to the second div

All boxes have set overflow to hidden:

```css
div.outer_box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 160px;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.containter{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset -5px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    top: -51px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 160px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
div.containter2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top:120px;
    width: 380px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer_box">
            <div class="containter">
                <div class="containter2">
                    <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold; font-size: 22px;">
                        <span style="color:red;">OUR</span>
                        <span style="color:darkblue;">BRANDS</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

to work on Safari or IE: use below lines for **rotation**:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(20deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg); /* Safari */
transform: rotate(20deg);
```

and for **shadow**:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -15px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset -15px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: inset -15px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

**B - when your button's width can vary:**
If you have solid (not transparent) background-color of this button you can also create "shader-div" and pleaced it to the right:

```css
div.outer_box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
    width: 160px;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.outer_box:hover{
    width: 220px;
}
div.text_container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top:0px;
    width: 380px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.right_cut_off{
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
    top: -60px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer_box">
            <div class="text_container">
                <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold; font-size: 22px;">
                    <span style="color:red;">OUR</span>
                    <span style="color:darkblue;">BRANDSXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="right_cut_off"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if the outer_box width is unknown? like display: block

Comment: added second possibility